# Expression types in a compiler written in Ocaml

Tags: compiler-construction, types, ocaml

I am writing a small compiler in Ocaml. In `ast.mli`, i have defined 2 kinds of expressions

```
type int_expr =
  | Integer_constant of int
  | Evar of string
  | Ebinop of binop * int_expr * int_expr
  | Ecell of int_expr * int_expr (* Sheet[ , ] *)

type bool_expr = 
  | Bool_constant of bool
  | Bcmp of cmp * int_expr * int_expr
  | Band of bool_expr * bool_expr
  | Bor of bool_expr * bool_expr
  | Bnot of bool_expr
```

In `interp.ml`, i want to define a function called `eval_expression` to evaluate any expression which could either be int_expr or bool_expr

```
let rec eval_expression env = function
  | Integer_constant n -> Integer n
  | Ebinop (op, n, m) -> ...
  | Evar x -> ...
  | Ecell (r, c) -> ... 
  | Bool_constant b -> ...
  | Bnot c -> ...
  | Bor (c1, c2) -> ...
  | Band (c1, c2) -> ...
```

But it returns an error while compiling:

```
ocamlc  -c interp.ml
File "interp.ml", line 63, characters 4-19:
Error: This pattern matches values of type Ast.bool_expr
       but a pattern was expected which matches values of type Ast.int_expr
make: *** [interp.cmo] Error 2
```

Could anyone tell me how I could change the structure of my expression types so that `eval_expression` works? Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you show the exact line the failure is reported at and a few lines extra of surrounding context?

Comment: The exact line of failure (63) is `| Bool_constant b -> ...` in the `eval_expression` function in my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to write another type for arbitrary-typed expressions:

```
type expr = Iexpr of int_expr
          | Bexpr of bool_expr
```

and a type for final values which could be either integer or boolean

```
type value = Ivalue of int
           | Bvalue of bool
```

and write a function `evaluate : expr -> value`.

For what it's worth, I've never felt that statically separating the allowable expressions in this manner into int-typed and bool-typed expressions was ever really worth it in an ML-like language.  You end up with a lot of duplicated syntax once you add richer types to your object language.  What you really want is to kick the object language types into the type strata of your implementation language, but that ends up being pretty ugly in ML.  It's slightly nicer in Haskell's richer type and kind machinery, but it still feels like a very affected programming style.

In the end, for little throwaway interpreters I usually just code up separate `tp` and `expr` types for the type and expressions of my object language and write the eval as `expr -> tp -> value`